# Javascript screen size detector and shows an image

Tags: javascript, image, hide, show

How can I do a Javascript text for this:
I need that when I visit my website with a phone, an image apears, but, if I'm watching it from a computer, the image is hidden. 
Thanks

Comment: Look up media queries in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try using just CSS:

```
#yourImage {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
#yourImage {
   display: inline;
}
```

This page lists some more media queries: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/